# How to use ImageMagick to place a watermark in multiple locations on an image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am currently using imagemagick through the command line to place a watermark in multiple locations on another image, but the way I am doing it seems like it probably isn't the best way to go about doing it.

Here is how I am doing it:

```
exec("convert 'originalImage.jpg' 'watermark.jpg' -gravity NorthWest -geometry +3+3 -define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve -composite 'finalImage.jpg'");
exec("convert 'finalImage.jpg' 'watermark.jpg' -gravity NorthEast -geometry +3+3 -define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve -composite 'finalImage.jpg'");
exec("convert 'finalImage.jpg' 'watermark.jpg' -gravity SouthWest -geometry +3+3 -define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve -composite 'finalImage.jpg'");
```

This is (1) taking originalImage.jpg and adding watermark.jpg to the top-left corner (with a 3px margin from the top left, using 30% opacity), then (2) taking that resulting finalImage.jpg and adding the watermark to the top-right corner, and then (3) taking that finalImage.jpg again and adding the watermark to the bottom-left corner.

So it is recreating the file three times to come up with the final image.  Is there a shorthand way to do this same thing without having to save the file three separate times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using multiple "-draw" options:
"-draw" doesn't have a "dissolve" option so you'd need to prepare the
watermark image ahead of time to have 30% alpha.

```
convert watermark.jpg -alpha set -channel alpha -fx .30 watermark30.png
convert originalImage.jpg \
   -gravity NorthWest -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 watermark30.png" \
   -gravity NorthEast -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 watermark30.png" \
   -gravity SouthWest -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 watermark30.png" \
   finalImage.jpg
```

You could combine this with Mark's good recommendation to use the MPR format instead of watermark30.png.  I did a couple of  "-draw" versus "-composite" timing tests, and it appears that Mark's method is somewhat faster.

---

I hope you don't mind my editing your post - delete it if you wish - but here is how a single command might look that does the same all in one go:

```
convert watermark.jpg -alpha set -channel alpha -fx .30 -write MPR:wm30 +delete original.jpg \
   -gravity NorthWest -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 'MPR:wm30'" \
   -gravity NorthEast -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 'MPR:wm30'" \
   -gravity SouthWest -draw "image over 3,3 0,0 'MPR:wm30'" \
   finalImage.jpg
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not at a computer, so untested, but this should be close:

```
convert originalImage.jpg \( watermark.jpg -write MPR:wm \) \
   -define compose:args=30,100 -compose dissolve            \
          -gravity NorthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
   MPR:wm -gravity NorthEast -geometry +3+3 -composite      \
   MPR:wm -gravity SouthWest -geometry +3+3 -composite finalImage.jpg
```

MPR is a RAM-based *"Magick Persistent Register"* which I use to avoid needing to keep re-reading the `watermark.jpg`.

The `compose` arguments persist until changed, so I don't repeat them. It may not be necessary to repeat the second and third `-geometry`.

Comment: That should work, but it might be simpler and possibly faster to just do one "convert" with several "-draw image ..." options.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson, can you give a more complete example of the method you are mentioning? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell.  I'll give this a shot tomorrow morning and let you know how it goes.